# How to Rename all variables at once in SQL Server SP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used `@RowsNumber` Variables `4` times. I just want that all of them gets rename at once In SQL Server. Is any shortcut key for it? like we use `CTRL + r + r` in Visual Studio using `C#`.

Below is my sample stored procedure where I have used `@RowsNumber` and want to rename it at once.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [IMProject].[AutoTaskInsertInToProjects]
@ProjectId int 
AS
BEGIN

Declare
@Portal int,
@Product varchar(20),
@Counter int,
@RowsNumber varchar(50)
            SELECT @RowsNumber = SelectedProductIds , @Portal = PortalId   FROM IMProject.Projects WHERE Id = @ProjectId    
            select @Counter= Count(items) from dbo.SplitCSV(@RowsNumber)
            Select items Into #Temp2  From   dbo.SplitCSV(@RowsNumber)
            declare @procId int = 0
            WHILE ( @Counter > 0)
            Begin    
                    SELECT TOP 1 @procId = items from #Temp2
                   insert into SuperAdmin.Issues (PortalId, ProductId, AssignedToId, PriorityId , StatusId, DT_Created,  DT_Modified, [Name] , ProjectId,    [Type] , [Description] , StartDate , Deleted)
                                        select    @portal, ProductId,  AssignedToId, PriorityId,     1,      GETDATE(),    GETDATE(), [Name] , @ProjectId, 'AutoTask' , [Description] ,GETDATE() , 0
                    from IMProject.AutoTasks where PortalId = @Portal AND ProductId = @procId AND Deleted = 0
                    delete from #Temp2 where items = @procId
                    SET @Counter= @Counter-1
            END
END
```

Comment: When using the replacement (through Ctrl+F, idk if there's an other shortcut), you can chose to replace all directly.

Comment: Be very careful if you have more than 1 variable that share the same name at the beginning. For example `@ProductName` and `@ProductNamePartial`. In this case make sure to replace the longest one first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below short cut & replace that name with new name as you wish.

```
Ctrl + H
```

Comment: So far your answer is helpful, but I am just waiting for a better shortcut like we have ctrl + r r in VS.

Comment: @NaveedUllah I can understand you query but I have never used other than this. This shortcut also work in Visual Studio. Yes you can customize your replace with several options like Case-sensitive.

Comment: This answer is not at all what OP needs, I think. For starters, there can be multiple scopes of variables and renaming one should not affect others in different scopes.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally Visual Studio should have some refactor capability which can rename a variable directly, throughout the source file or even the entire project.  That not being available, we can try the following regex replacement within your source file:

```
Find:    @RowsNumber\b
Replace: @NewRowsNumber
```

This answer assumes that `@RowsNumber` would never appear inside of another string.  The word boundary on the right ensures this requirement on the right side, but no the left.

Answer (score 1):

you can use *Find and Replace* using `Ctrl + H` in SSMS

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want the Find and Replace Method. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> and an overlay like the below will appear in the top right of your SSMS:

[image]

Type the string you want to replace in the "Find..." box (In this example `@RowNumber`), and then in Find... type the string you want to replace it with. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to replace ALL instances of that string.

The Find and Replace pane, by default, uses Regular Expressions (note in my picture is has the .* icon highlighted). If you *are* using regular expression mode, don't forget to escape certain special characters. For example, "dbo.MyTable" would need to be "dbo\.MyTable". Of course, you can change the search to Match Case (Aa) and Match word `Abl`.